# Saving (and averaging) Large Sparse Numpy Array

Tags: python, csv, numpy, sparse-matrix

I have written a code that generates a large 3d numpy array of data observations (floats). The dimensions are (33,000 x 2016 x 53), which corresponds to (#obs.locations x 5min_intervals_perweek x weeks_in_leapyear). It is very sparse (about 1.5% of entries are filled).

Currently I do this by calling:

```
my3Darray = np.zeros(33000,2016,53)
```

or

```
my3Darray = np.empty(33000,2016,53)
```

My loop then indexes into the array one entry at a time and updates 1.5% with floats (this part is actually very fast). I then need to:

1. Save each 2D (33000 x 2016) slice as a CSV or other 'general format' data file
2. Take the mean over the 3rd dimension (so I should get a 33000 x 2016 matrix)

I have tried saving with:

```
for slice_2d_week_i in xrange(nweeks):
   weekfile = str(slice_2d_week_i)
   np.savetxt(weekfile, my3Darray[:,:,slice_2d_week_i], delimiter=",")
```

However, this is extremely slow and the empty entries in the output show up as

```
0.000000000000000000e+00
```

which makes the file sizes huge.

Is there a more efficient way to save (possibly leaving blanks for entries that were never updated?) Is there a better way to allocate the array besides np.zeros or np.empty? And how can I take the mean over the 3rd dimension while ignoring non-updated entries ( mean(my3Darray,3) does not ignore the 0 entries ).

Comment: you may want to consider using one of the `scipy.sparse` formats then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save in one of numpy's binary formats, here's one I use: [np.savez](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html#numpy.savez).

You can average with `np.sum(a, axis=2) / np.sum(a != 0, axis=2)`. Keep in mind that this will still give you `NaN`'s when there are zeros in the denominator.

Comment: Thank you -- I will look at np.saves. I tried the a!=0 logical indexing method, but found that it was really slow (several minutes) to run these logicals over this size array.

Comment: Try a scipy.sparse array instead.

Comment: As far as I can tell, scipy.sparse is not multidimensional. I could just make a set of 53 2D arrays rather than one (33000 x 2016 x 53) 3Darray. But then I still have to take the mean flattening the 53 arrays.

Comment: Or make a 66528000x53 sparse 2D array and take the above "mean" `(axis=1)`. Not ideal, I admit.